# Can EarlGrey be used as test tool only having ipa file?

Tags: automation, appium, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, earlgrey

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm planning to develop a UI test automation for an iOS application.
The problem is that I don't have access to the source code but only the finished ipa file of the app.
Is there a possibility to write UI tests with EarlGrey or do I need the source code of the app?

With Appium it should be possible to write UI tests without the source code.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original EarlGrey by Google required access to iOS project, you can check [here](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/install-and-run.md) the setup.

The new [EarlGrey 2](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/tree/earlgrey2#using-earlgrey-20) is actually has a similar concept and you need to have source code to use it.

Appium can use developer-signed **.app** file on simulator. If you want to run tests on real device you need have developer-signed **.ipa** file plus [re-sign WebDriverAgent](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/) with the same iOS developer account.

So technically Appium does not require source code, but you need to have access to iOS developer certificates that been used for build